# What does "instance [safe]" mean in ghci ":info" output?

Tags: haskell, ghci

In `ghci`, I declare a data type as follows.

```
data Example = MakeExample deriving Show
```

Then, when I call `:info Example` to see that the derived `Show` instance is recognized, I get the following output.

```
> :i Example
data Example = MakeExample      -- Defined at <interactive>:17:1
instance [safe] Show Example -- Defined at <interactive>:17:37
```

The `Show` instance is recognized as expected. However, I do not understand why that `[safe]` is there.

By contrast, `[safe]` does not appear when I call `:info` on `Bool`.

```
> :i Bool
data Bool = False | True        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
instance Bounded Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Enum Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Eq Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Ord Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Read Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Show Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
```

**What does `instance [safe]` mean in `ghci`'s `:info` output?**